# Program not linking when compiled via a Makefile and using an external linked library

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a `makefile` that I've been using to compile my shared libraries which reads in the files from different folders and then builds the objects and binaries in their own folders. The folder structure I'm using is roughly displayed below.

```
-Folder
 |
 +--API Header Files Dir
 |
 +--Library (.so) Project One
 |  +-- MakeFile Project One
 |  +-- src (*.cpp files)
 |  +-- inc (*.h files)
 |  +-- obj (compiled object files)
 |  +-- bin (compiled project)
 |
 +--Library (.so) Project Two
 |  +-- MakeFile Project Two
 |  +-- src (*.cpp files)
 |  +-- inc (*.h files)
 |  +-- obj (compiled object files)
 |  +-- bin (compiled project)
 |
```

I've tried to put together a general `makefile` that can accomplish this and this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15724/improving-makefile-and-general-c-project-structure?rq=1) was quite nice and I've edited my original `makefile` to the best of my understanding to try to make this work.

One problem - while it works ok when I'm just compiling source code only, I've been trying to use it in a project where I'm linking to some external library files and it no longer works. I keep getting the following error:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/libTest_v1_5.o] Error 1
```

I've managed to set up a project in Code::Blocks to test all the project files and that compiles ok, so it's just my `makefile` that is incorrect. I guess I've gotten one of the rules wrong.

Here's my file:

```
######################################################################################
# Purpose               :   MakeFile for building shared library & coupled projects
#
# Date Created          :   25-06-2015
# Date Modified         :   
#
# Note                  : 1. make         : to build unoptimized standard build
#                         2. make debug   : to build  with debug symbols
#                         3. make release : to build  with symbols stripped and optimized
#
# Usage                 : change the "TARGET" to your program name or else use as it is
######################################################################################
ifndef _ARCH
_ARCH := $(shell uname -m)
export _ARCH
endif # wanted to use this in my build directories but figured it's not necessary?

NAME := Test
MAJOR := 1
MINOR := 5
VERSION := v$(MAJOR)_$(MINOR)
TARGET := lib$(NAME)_$(VERSION).o

SRCEXT   := cpp
SRCDIR   := src
INCPATH  := inc
OBJDIR   := obj
BINDIR   := bin
BIN_DEBUGDIR   := $(BINDIR)/debug
API_DIR := /home/API/Multibody/Coupling


INCLUDES := -I. \
            -I$(INCPATH) \
            -I$(API_DIR)

# C++ compiler flag
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -W -march=native -c $(INCLUDES)

# Linker parameter flags
LDFLAGS  := -L$(API_DIR)/lib 
# Linker library flags
LDLIBS   += -lCouplingClientV2_2_0


SRCS    := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.$(SRCEXT)')
SRCDIRS := $(shell find . -name '*.$(SRCEXT)' -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJS    := $(patsubst %.$(SRCEXT),$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))


###########################################################################
# Rules to compile our files  - Do not change below this line!
###########################################################################

ifeq ($(SRCEXT), cpp)
CC       = $(CXX)
else
CXXFLAGS  += -std=gnu99
endif

.PHONY: all debug release clean distclean 


all: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

# Build debug library
debug: CXXFLAGS += -g
debug: clean $(BIN_DEBUGDIR)/$(TARGET)


# strip all symbols from release verison
release: LDFLAGS += -s 
release: CXXFLAGS += -O2
release: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    @echo "Linking $@..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    @echo "$@ sucessfully built."

$(BIN_DEBUGDIR)/$(TARGET): buildrepo $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    @echo "Linking $@..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(LDLIBS) 
    @echo "$@ sucessfully built."

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.$(SRCEXT)
    @echo "Generating dependencies for $<..."
    @$(call make-depend,$<,$@,$(subst .o,.d,$@))
    @echo "Compiling $<..."
    @$(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) -r $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    $(RM) -r $(BIN_DEBUGDIR)/$(TARGET)

buildrepo:
    @$(call make-repo)

define make-repo
   for dir in $(SRCDIRS); \
   do \
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$$dir; \
   done
endef


# usage: $(call make-depend,source-file,object-file,depend-file)
define make-depend
  $(CC) -MM       \
        -MMD      \
        -MF $3    \
        -MP       \
        -MT $2    \
        $(CXXFLAGS) \
        $(LDFLAGS) \
        $1
endef
```

Any comments on how to improve the makefile would be great. Any answers as to what I'm doing wrong in the linking would be even better!!

#### Update:

Here's the output from code::blocks for a successfully compiled project from the exact same source code and library. My problem only relates to the `makefile` - not what's defined anywhere in the project source code or API files.

```
-------------- Build: Release in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -O2 -Wfatal-errors -Wall   -I../Multibody/EDEMCoupling -c /home/API/Multibody/EPT/src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp -o obj/Release/Multibody/EPT/src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.o

g++ -L../Multibody/EDEMCoupling/lib   -o bin/Release/EPT_Test obj/Release/Multibody/EPT/src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.o   -s  /home/API/Multibody/EDEMCoupling/lib/libEDEMCouplingClientV2_2_0.so 
Output size is 48.21 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 6 seconds)
```

#### Makefile Output:

Here's the terminal output after calling make. It never gets past the stage of compiling the object file from the source.cpp (This is a very simple project and has only a single cpp file in it). I don't really understand why since this file was working perfectly for all the projects that compiled shared libraries - I've just removed -shared  and -fPIC from the flags.

```
*Generating dependencies for src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp...
Compiling src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp...
src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:199: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
/home/API/Multibody/EDEMCoupling/ApiTypes.h: At global scope:
/home/API/Multibody/EDEMCoupling/ApiTypes.h:193: warning: ‘const char* NApi::delim()’ defined but not used
Linking bin/Test_v1_5.o...
obj/src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.o: In function `main':
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x546): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::IEDEMCoupling()'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::initialiseCoupling()'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x5e3): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::connectCoupling(bool, char*)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x6e0): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryId(char const*, int&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x71b): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryId(char const*, int&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x756): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryId(char const*, int&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x16c4): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::setGridCellSize(double const&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x16e9): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::setNumberOfCores(int const&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x1702): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getEDEMTimeStep(double&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x1725): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getNumberOfTimesteps(unsigned int&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x175c): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getEDEMTime(double&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x17ef): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getEDEMTimesteps(double*, unsigned int&, unsigned int)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x1d66): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::setEDEMTime(double const&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x1d7f): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getEDEMTime(double&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x1eb7): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::setEDEMTime(double const&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x1ed0): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getEDEMTime(double&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x21e7): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryPosition(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&, NApiEDEM::C3x3Matrix&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x221a): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryPosition(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&, NApiEDEM::C3x3Matrix&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2358): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryTranslation(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2562): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryVelocity(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2710): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryTranslation(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x291a): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryVelocity(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2afd): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryForces(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2b6e): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::getGeometryForces(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2c0a): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::removeGeometry(char const*)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x2c28): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::showSimulator()'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x3b21): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::selectGeometrySection(char const*, int&)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x3b39): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::removeGeometry(char const*)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x3b48): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::showSimulator()'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x3fd5): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::isConnected() const'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x4059): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::setGeometryMotion(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue const&, NApiEDEM::C3x3Matrix const&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue const&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue const&, double, bool)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x40bd): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::setGeometryMotion(int, NApiEDEM::C3dValue const&, NApiEDEM::C3x3Matrix const&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue const&, NApiEDEM::C3dValue const&, double, bool)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x40f4): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::isConnected() const'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x4119): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::simulate(double const&, double)'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x4dbb): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::~IEDEMCoupling()'
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x4dd1): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::~IEDEMCoupling()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/Test_v1_5.o] Error 1*
```

Comment: `ld`'s output please. Your `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` says only that it exited with a error.

Comment: 'Linking bin/libEPT_v3_0.o...
obj/src/EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.o: In function `main':
EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp:(.text+0x546): undefined reference to `NApiEDEM::IEDEMCoupling::IEDEMCoupling()''

Comment: And where is that symbol supposed to be coming from?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking but IEDEMCoupling is defined in  the file "IEDEMCouplingV2_2_0.h" source file which is in the API_DIR. The linked library file is in the subdirectory of the folder.

Comment: In `IEDEMCouplingV2_2_0.h`, does `IEDEMCoupling` (whether it's a _class_ or _namespace_) have `IEDEMCoupling` (_method_ or _func_/_class_)? (that you are calling from `EPT_Consolidation_Damped_v11.cpp`). Also when building a big project consisting of several structurally independent sub-projects, it would probably be a good idea that each sub-project has its own `Makefile`, and in the _main_ `Makefile` you just `cd` in each sub-project's folder and run `make` (to avoid _overcomplicating_ the main `Makefile`).

Comment: @CristiFati There is no problems with the source code or compiled libraries that I'm linking too - it is all to do with the make file. I've tested it with code::blocks and although a little fiddly to set up  the project it, once it's set up it complies perfectly and works - I've tested that much. I've updated the post to include the code::block output that works properly.

Comment: How does the output from the `make` differ from the build that works?  What command line does the `make` give?  Why is it different from the working one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added the terminal output from a make call. It's not even creating the object files, never-mind linking to the additional library.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't show the information that matters: the command that is executed.  I loathe makefiles that hide what's going on.  If it's yours, fix it.  If it isn't, use the `-n` option to show what is executed.  If that doesn't show the command line either, then things are dire and you have to work harder; we'll need to look at `-p` or even (perish the thought) `-d` output.  Or decide that manual linking works, report a broken make file to the author and get on with life.